# From non coalesced access to coalesced memory access CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, memory-access

I was wondering if there is any simple way to transform a non-coalesced memory access into a coalesced one. Let's take the example of this array:

```
dW[[w0,w1,w2][w3,w4,w5][w6,w7][w8,w9]]
```

Now, i know that if Thread 0 in block 0 access `dW[0]` and then Thread 1 in block 0 access `dw[1]`, that's a coalesced access in the global memory. The problem is that i have two operations. The first one is coalesced as described above. But the second one isn't because Thread 1 in block 0 needs to do an operation on both `dW[0]`, `dW[1]` and `dW[2]`.

I know that the initial shape of the container allow or forbid the coalesced access. But `dW` is a very big array, and i can't transform it during the process.

Do you know if it's possible to aleviate this problem?

Comment: (1) did you benchmark your code and did the benchmark results tell you that uncoalesced memory access is a significant cause of slowdown? (2) no one will be able to help you with optimizing your memory accesses unless you post a [mcve] which actually shows the memory access pattern

Comment: Well, yes i did two benchmarks. And they confirmed the slowdown (not that much but it's a slow ...). As always it's still hard to show you a simple code because those operations are parts of a more complex program. I'll try to implement something that rise the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use shared memory maybe, that might work (or not, hard to tell without an example).

For instance, say the first operation access coalesced data and the second one strides a lot; this may speedup things

```
__shared__ int shared[BLOCK_SIZE];
// Load data global -> shared with coalesced access ; you may need to load a bit more before/after depending on you application
shared[tid] = global[some id]
syncthreads();
// Do the math with coalescing access
function0(shared[tid])
// Do the math with the non coalescing access
function1(shared[tid+-1 or wathever])
```

The idea is to load data in shared in a coalescent manner, and then use shared to do the math, since coalescent access do not matter with shared memory (but bank conflict do on the other hand ; that's usually fine though).

You'll have to give us more information if you want a more accurate help.
That's just a hint.